# Span of 3 linearly dependent vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

The vectors are $(1,1,1)$,$(1,2,0)$, and $(2,3,1)$. I have shown that they are linearly dependent but don't really know how to find their span. (Note: my lecturer just literally defined what a span is and didn't get to the part where we actually calculate spans, so I'm completely lost!). Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hint:  since the first two are (clearly) independent, any vector in the span can be written uniquely as $a(1,1,1)+b(1,2,0)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the third vector is a linear combination of the first two, and the first two are not scalar multiples of each other (that is, they are linearly independent), we have that the span is all linear combinations of the first two vectors. So,
$$
\mathrm{span}\left\{ \begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 1\\ 1 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 2\\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \right\} = \left\{ a\begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 1\\ 1 \end{pmatrix} + b\begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 2\\ 0 \end{pmatrix} : a, b \in \mathbb{R}\right\}.
$$
This is some plane in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$.

Answer (score 2):

Given a set of vectors their [**span**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_span) is given by the set of all linear combinations of those vectors.

In that case the span is

$$a(1,1,1)+b(1,2,0)+c(2,3,1)$$

Since the three vectors are linearly dependent but $(1,1,1)$ and $(1,2,0)$ are linearly independent the span is also given by

$$a(1,1,1)+b(1,2,0)$$

or by any other pair of the three vectors. In that case any pair is a basis for the span of the three given vectors.